# Drawing lights on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi i'm trying to draw lights in a canvas like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);

var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(150,150,0,150,150,150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,0)");
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

ctx.clearRect(300,0,600,300);

var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(450,150,0,450,150,150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,0)");
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(300,0,600,300);

</script>
```

The problem is when the lights overlap

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);

var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(150,150,0,150,150,150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,0)");
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

ctx.clearRect(200,0,500,300);

var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(350,150,0,350,150,150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,0)");
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(200,0,500,300);

</script>
```

I need the lights come together and not overlap
 also i need to see an image below the canvas
how can i Solve ?

[that's the effect i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4Xk.jpg)

I've used 2 canvas, 1 for scenery and 1 above for lights

This is almost what i'm looking for , but it remains a bit 'darker where the lights overlap, there is too little light in the center of each light, and it looks like a white light instead of a yellow light
http://jsfiddle.net/vgmc4m87/

Thanks

Comment: If you want them to interval firstly don't clear the canvas, for example [here is how it would look](https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xffnq/1/) without `clearRect()`. Note the overlapping area is darker since the items draw on-top of each other.

Comment: Also what about setting the background color first, and have the gradients move to transparent? [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xffnq/4/)

Comment: *"also i need to see an image below the canvas"* - I don't see how that effects the problem. You can simply draw an image on the canvas at the start and use the exact same solution mentioned in the solutions below.

Comment: Thanks but not exactly, see image in the edit

Comment: I'm confused, [what is wrong with doing this](https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xffnq/6/)? Seems like having a single canvas like I mentioned functionally works fine for what you want. Is it really necessary to have two canvas?

Comment: in your code lights cover image instead of discover it and don't overlap well 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4Xk.jpg

i don't know if is it possible with just a canvas

Comment: This is almost the effect i'm looking for , but still not perfect
http://jsfiddle.net/vgmc4m87/

Comment: That's a really good idea (much better than my complex one), You can add `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';` at the top to make it look a little better.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to overlap those two gradients, I would suggest a few things,

- Get rid of the `clearRect()`
- Change
  `grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,0)"); grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");`
   Such that the second color stop has 0 alpha component, this way the gradient will actually fade out as it goes towards the edge of the circle. And you can actually overlap circles only if they're fading towards the end.
- Don't use `fillRect()`, use arcs instead.

See, https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xffnq/3/. I've not preserved colours, but it should give you a good idea on how to proceed.

Comment: I would add `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen"` to your example, this will allow the shapes to interlace better.

Comment: No problem. *@OP*: Note you can mess around with this example to get the lighting how you want it. [Here is my attempt at doing that](https://jsfiddle.net/fL4xffnq/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @nisargjhaveri's answer setting `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"` creates a nice effect.

```js
function drawBackground() {
  var can = document.getElementById('background');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,255,255,1)");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(30,100,200,1)");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 150);
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 150, 0, 300);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(15,75,25,1)");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(30,150,50,1)");
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 150, 500, 300);
}

drawBackground();



var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var bg = document.getElementById("background");

var x1 = 150;
var y1 = 150;

var x2 = 350;
var y2 = 150;

var step1 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 1
};
var step2 = {
  x: -1,
  y: 1
};

function loop() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);

  // Create a white to transparent gradient for the circles
  
  // Circle one
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(x1, y1, 0, x1, y1, 150);
  grd.addColorStop(.75, "rgba(255,255,0,1)");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,0,0)");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.arc(x1, y1, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
  ctx.fill();

  // Circle two
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(x2, y2, 0, x2, y2, 150);
  grd.addColorStop(.75, "rgba(255,255,255,1)");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.arc(x2, y2, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
  ctx.fill();
  
  // Fill the white part with the background image.
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, bg.width, bg.height);
  
  // Fill the transparent part with gray.
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(63,63,63,1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  // clear the globalCompositeOperation
  ctx.restore();


  step1.x = x1 > c.width ? -1 : x1 < 0 ? 1 : step1.x;
  step1.y = y1 > c.height ? -1 : y1 < 0 ? 1 : step1.y;
  step2.x = x2 > c.width ? -1 : x2 < 0 ? 1 : step2.x;
  step2.y = y2 > c.height ? -1 : y2 < 0 ? 1 : step2.y;
  x1 += step1.x;
  y1 += step1.y;
  x2 += step2.x;
  y2 += step2.y;


  setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 60);
}

loop()
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="500" height="300" style='display:none'></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok. the problem now is: I used clearRect() and gradient cause i need to see an image below the canvas, is it possible ?

Comment: @Miky I changed the output to be like the jsfiddle you posted.  The yellow color is lost so you'll need to add that back.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/p3k7cwqs/

javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16000000/Beautiful-Cat-cats-16096437-1280-800.jpg";

image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 400);

    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(150, 150, 0, 0, 150, 200);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,1)");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.arc(150, 150, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    ctx.fill();

    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(350, 150, 0, 350, 150, 200);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,0,1)");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.arc(350, 150, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    ctx.fill();
};
```

Comment: Thanks but in your code lights cover image instead of discover it 
[image][1]
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4Xk.jpg